# generate RSA public/private key based on a passphrase using bouncy Castel library in c#

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, pem

I'd like to generate an RSA key pair with a private key encrypted with passphrase using the Bouncy Castel Library in C# and save them to separate files so that I can use them to encrypt or decrypt things whenever I need to...

I'm able to generate an RSA keypair and store them in separate PEM files. I believe it is in PKCS1 format, but I can't seem to figure out how to generate Keypair based on the password.

I looked on the official site, https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp, but couldn't find any examples.
I also searched all the way through stack overflow with no success.

Answer (score 3):

At least I figured out How to generate RSA Keypair with passphrase to encrypt the private key, using AES-256-CBC with BouncyCastle C# (1.9.2)
Note: Both the key's are in PEM format.
I got help from the following Link: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xdc447ca00ad5a1a69649f92339871f7caeada0c6c47b8b39ccad91e46cf75d74&fullName=Certificate.cs&project=nicholaspaun/Kalkulator1

```
//Create Random
CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();

//RSAKeyPairGenerator generates the RSA keypair based on the random number and strength of the key required
RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
rsaKeyPairGen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(randomGenerator), 2048));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = rsaKeyPairGen.GenerateKeyPair();

//Extracting the private key from the pair
RsaKeyParameters Privatekey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;

//Extracting the public key from the pair
RsaKeyParameters Publickey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;

//Creating public key in pem format\
TextWriter pubtxtWriter = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pubpemWriter = new PemWriter(pubtxtWriter);
pubpemWriter.WriteObject(Publickey);
pubpemWriter.Writer.Flush();
//now save the follwing string variable into a file. that's our public key
string print_publicKey = pubtxtWriter.ToString();

//encrypted Private Key
string password = "xxxxx";  //give desired password, with good strength
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.Private;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw);
pw.WriteObject(privateKey, "AES-256-CBC", password.ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
pw.Writer.Close();
pw.Writer.Flush();
//now save the follwing string variable into a file. that's our "Encrypted private key"
string encprvKey = sw.ToString();
```